# How to configure a store to read a raw array of numbers from an ajax/rest call?

Tags: extjs, extjs6.5.1

I am trying to figure out how to configure a `Store` to read in a raw JSON array of numbers from a `GET` request via an AjaxProxy.

It demands *`Please associate a Model with the store, or add one or more Fields to the store.`* I do not have a model and there are no fields, it is just a raw JSON array. The `ArrayStore` does not seem to be the correct thing either, as it is looking for an *array of arrays* from what the documentation says.

Here is an example of the JSON that the `GET` request returns:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

These numbers represent unique `id`s in a system, not that that really matters.

I have never tried to do this before, I have had no problems when the response is an array of JSON objects or a JSON object with fields.

Here is how far I have gotten:

```
Ext.define('fivestar.store.NumberStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'NumberStore',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

I have read through the documentation, searched far and wide and I only found one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539182/extjs-5-load-a-very-simple-string-array-in-store/28593300#28593300) that says to `transform` the data and add a `field`. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526764/how-to-retrieve-json-data-array-from-extjs-store?rq=1) but it does not have enough code to explain how to use the answer. Is there any other way that is not so *heavy*?

#### What am I missing?

Comment: To clarify, what are you expecting to end up in the store? 10 records with an id 1 through 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the transform method to promote the raw data into objects:

```
Ext.define('MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data1.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            transform: raw => raw.map(v => ({ id: v }))
        }
    }
});

var s = new MyStore();
s.load(() => {
    console.log(s.getRange().map(r => r.id));
});
```

Fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25ho).